# Como puedo modificar los Modal de Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css

Basicamente lo que estoy intentnado hacer es que si las fotos fueron sacadas horizontalmente, el modal tengo un tamaño, y si fueron sacados verticalmente que tengan otro tamaño.

Por un lado tengo las imagenes verticales que se salen del Modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por otro las que fueron sacadas horizontalmente;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las imagenes son traidas de la base de datos y cargadas con un ajax, por lo que estuve tratando de adaptarles el tamaño desde ahi, con javascript:

```
while (i < result.length) {
                    var carusel = document.getElementById("Entrega_" + entrega);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item active');
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'd-block w-100 modal-content');
                        img.setAttribute('id', "img01")
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', result[i].path);                       
                        carusel.appendChild(div);
                        i++;
                    }
                    else {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item');
                        var img = document.createElement('img');
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'd-block w-100 modal-content');
                        img.setAttribute('id', "img01")
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', result[i].path);
                        carusel.appendChild(div);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                modal.style.display = "block";

                var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");

                // the added if-statement to change the max-width
                if (modalImg.naturalWidth > modalImg.naturalHeight) {
                    modalImg.style.maxWidth = '50vw';
                } else {
                    modalImg.style.maxWidth = '30vw';
                    modalImg.style.maxHeight = '';
                }
            }
```

Pero no parece estar cambiandolo.

Y con Css:

```
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 2%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    text-align: center;
}

.modal-content{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 30vw;
    max-height:85vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Pero tampoco veo resultados. Me podrian dar una mano con ésto?

Comment: Probaste a darle a la imágen 100% en maxHeight ?

Comment: Si pero la imagen sale de la pantalla directamente jajaja

Answer (score 1):

Quita todo eso y prueba con esto solo con CSS:

```
.modal-dialog {
  display: table;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

Lo he usado en algunos lugares y más o menos me funciona bien así.
Si acaso, en lugar de modificar el `modal-dialog` (que puede afectar a **todos** los modales de tu web) agrega una nueva clase al elemento que tiene la clase `modal-dialog` que quieras que funcione de ese modo y que tenga esas propiedades CSS que he puesto más arriba.

Ya nos cuentas si te sirve.

Comment: Me funcionó con que las imagenes estén dentro del modal, pero aún asi algunas de las imágenes verticales se salen de la pantalla, y las horizontales estoy intentnado agrandarlas pero tampoco puedo, se siguen viendo chicas. Pero muchas gracias!

Comment: En bootstrap hay la clase [img-fluid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/images/#responsive-images) que quizás te convenga utilizar para eso... Mira a ver si te sirve de algo también.

Comment: Es raro, estoy probando de usar `modal-xl` pero no me lo toma tampoco...

Comment: bueno, si estas usando el código de mi respuesta debe estar interfiriendo en ello